# How to check MSBuild and .Net framework version of a project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

I have a project which was written by using C#.What i want to do is to learn MSBuild version of the project.I opened the project in Visual Studio 2019.
I found a csproj file on project and It contains these lines

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

As I understand from Lex li answer project build version 15.0 so I should build it visual studio 2017.Am i right? I opened the project in visual studio 2019.

Comment: I'm afraid it's really difficult to help you figure this out in a Q&A format. Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying and what problems you run into? Would it maybe help to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ and see if you can find a tutorial to follow?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking for, but if you open `.csproj` (not in SDK style) file in a text editor, the MSBuild version number and target framework version are clearly there.

Comment: Thank you for answering @LexLi.I updated my question after your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the project -> unload it -> edit it
you will find all the relevant information related with the project and build.
then again Reload the project.

Here this link might help you.
[Walkthrough: Use MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019)